# PHP strtotime giving wrong date with GMT conversion?

Tags: php, date, strtotime, gmt

I'm reading a Last-Modified header which as a string is "Mon, 21 May 2013 09:10:30 GMT" and trying to compare that to my local time() (New Zealand). But I've just noticed that strtotime is making the date the "27" instead of "21" when "Mon, " is included in the string. Is that normal? Am I doing something wrong? Think I'm missing something...

```
$strtotime = strtotime("Mon, 21 May 2013 09:10:30 GMT");
$strtotime_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$strtotime);

//[strtotime] => 1369645830
//[strtotime_date] => 2013-05-27 21:10:30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The reason for the error is that there is nothing like `Mon, 21 May 2013` from my calendar `21`<sup>`st`</sup> `May` is  `Tuesday`
2. [From PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> **To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.**

Examples

```
$strtotime = strtotime("Tue, 21 May 2013 09:10:30 GMT");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $strtotime),PHP_EOL;

$strtotime = DateTime::createFromFormat("D, d M Y g:i:s O", "Tue, 21 May 2013 09:10:30 GMT");
echo $strtotime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Output

```
2013-05-21 11:10:30  <- strtotime
2013-05-21 09:10:30  <- datetime
```

Comment: Ah. Think you solved that one. I had manually copied and changed the date to test it and missed changing the "Mon" to "Tue". :|

Answer (score 1):

According to php.net, this format may actually be invalid; there's a list of acceptable formats here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php - day of the week is not mentioned.

Comment: Confirmed trimming off the Mon, at the beginning yeilds correct results.

Comment: Everywhere I've looked "Mon, ..." is the format being used for the Last-Modified header so I'm guessing others have run into the same problem. Do you know if I can safely exclude the "Mon, " when sending the Last-Modified header without screwing things up?