# year greater than current year and year lesser than current year not showing properly in fuelphp

Tags: php, date, fuelphp

In fuelphp project, I have published date which in format 'Y-m-d' is stored as strtotime(Input::post('published_date')).Now I query for past events and future events as follows:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$today = strtotime($date);

In query I do as follows:
if($params->event_type == 'future') {
   $query .= " AND contents.published_date > " .$today;
} elseif($params->event_type == 'past') {
   $query .= " AND contents.published_date < " .$today;
}
```

The query is running successfully and it's giving me correct data too but now when I echo published date year less than or greater than current year (2015) auto becomes 2015 and not the expected year. i.e. if future published date is 2020-10-14 it becomes 2015-10-14. Same is the case for past published date. What is the problem here or am I doing something wrong?
Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How do you echo `published date year`? What is `published date`? It seems there are two `published date`. One is from Input::post, the other is from database.

Comment: @kenjis No, there ism't 2 published date. I have written the format for which date is added in form i.e. 'Y-m-d' and how this date is stored in database as strtotime(Input::post('published_date')). I echo published date as follows.
<?php echo date('d', $published_date); ?> <?php echo date('F Y', $published_date); ?>

Comment: Got the answer and solution [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658640/php-strtotime-giving-wrong-date-with-gmt-conversion